# Can't Boot Windows (Gives "Repair Windows" Option)

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, bootloader

I have a few extra hardrvies without anything on them. So about a week ago I created a "Live" Usb to see if my system was compatible.

After a week of testing and playing I liked it enough to install it (Ubuntu 13.10) and yesterday I installed it to a second hard drive, everything went OK but I think its good to note that Ubuntu installer said something along the lines of

```
"Ubuntu did not detect any other operating systems"
```

However I did have Win7(64bit) installed. I thought nothing of this at the time (as I am installing to a second drive).

Now I selected the bottom option,

1. created a partition table,
2. Partition off 70gbs for "/" (EXT4),
3. 8GB for swap (80gb drive).

For boot loader I put it on the same drive as install. I did this because I did not want to

- Interfere with the MBR and windows boot loader
- I wanted to select it in the F12 menu of my bios (Select the drive
  too boot from)
- I did not want Grub to replace WBL for multiple reasons (I hear
  its unstable, and Refer to letter the above point)

Then today, I wanted to boot into windows. I restart the computer, my BIOS goes to Windows (Like I wanted, no OS select) then windows says it needs to repair or start. I have tried both. The repair option goes into a loop of, the boot screen, loading windows files. Now start windows (Somehow) boots me into Linux.

When Linux starts It says it had a error, specifically a crash.

Also, I can view all my windows files too! My data is intact!

It is also good to note my specs:

- EvGA GT 640
- i5 3.1 Quad
- 8gb Ram
- Gigabyte mother board w/ 3-D Bios

4 Drives:

- 160gb SATA NTFSWindows)
- 80gb  SATA NTFS(Renders ect)
- 80GB SATA EXT4(Linux)
- 1TB SATA NTFS(Games, Fraps records)

Now it seems while I was trying NOT to screw up my windows boot loader I seem to have.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to run Boot-Repair but with multiple drives do not run the auto repair as that will install grub to every drive. You can uncheck auto repair, check update MBR and in advanced options choose which system to install a boot loader to which drive.

Some with mulitple drives install Windows to one drive, but because BIOS was set for another drive the (hidden) 100MB Windows boot partition is on another drive than main install.

Boot-Info report from Boot-Repair will show all the details if you cannot fix it.  But if Windows is missing boot Files you need Windows repairs.

Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot.:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Ok, my files had finished backing up, now on boot repair it doesn't see my windows drive. It shows Linux and my 2 other hard drives. Reading online it says to use "sda1" but sda# isn't anywhere. The others are labeled "sdb", "sdc"(Linux), "sdd". The also have things like "(Generic gptmbr)" and other things similar. http://paste.ubuntu.com/6095036/ <--- That is the paste it gave me when I ran the tester.

Comment: Also, "Some with mulitple drives install Windows to one drive, but because BIOS was set for another drive the (hidden) 100MB Windows boot partition is on another drive than main install."

When I check "Gparted" The windows 100mb partion is there, I installed windows before the other hardrives I belive.

Also I tried a repair of sdc

Comment: and it seemed to have now broken linux and I am wrirting this on a live cd. When booting to the live CD it also has a error.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6095144/ <--- new one. Sorry for string of comments :/